# Internal linking search box not working - WP 3.2

Tags: links

I'm developing on a local install of WP 3.2 and noticed that the search box inside the insert/edit link dialog is not working (Tiny MCE link button in the visual editor).

Has anyone else experienced this / know what might be causing it? The search indicator just spins without returning any results when I type in keywords which I know to be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was caused by the WP-o-Matic plugin which my client was using.

Comment: Please mark your question as _answered_.